# Find the closest time from a list of times

Tags: c#, comparison

So, here's the scenario. I have a file with a created time, and I want to choose a time from a list of times that that file's created time is closest or equal too...what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DateTime fileDate, closestDate;
ArrayList theDates;
long min = long.MaxValue;

foreach (DateTime date in theDates)
 if (Math.Abs(date.Ticks - fileDate.Ticks) < min)
 {
   min = Math.Abs(date.Ticks - fileDate.Ticks);
   closestDate = date;
 }
```

Comment: The other answers that sort the list of time diffs just to find the smallest one are engaging in overkill.  This approach is the most straightforward, although it's missing a Math.Abs() call.

Comment: @JeffK it depends on what you find more readable. Although this approach is likely to be faster, but needs both a Math.Abs and .Days or something for the TimeSpan.

Comment: @luvieere: It doesn't work well as it is. `Math.Abs` won't accept `TimeSpan` arguments.

Comment: Sorry about the omission, I remembered it wrong and I'm not at my development station right now so I could test.

Comment: @Yuriy - Readability first, I would agree.  In that vein, I actually find this solution **more** readable than the various "sort, then select the first one" versions.  For me, the sort makes big yellow question marks start bouncing over my head, as I wonder, "Why is this being sorted?  What am I missing"  And then there's the efficiency argument.  Sorting is O(N log N) at best, while a simple scan is O(N).

Comment: I'm liking this so far, but I have a few issues...first, I get a "Use of unassigned local variable on the int min;...then, date.Milliseconds doesn't work, but date.Millisecond does; however, date.Millisecond is always zero...

Comment: This answer is completely wrong.  The `millisecond` property goes from 0 to 999 every second.  If the file was created at 12:00:00.001, this method will show 6:55:32.005 as being closer than 12:01:01.500.

Comment: Furthermore, if you initialize `min = 0`, no absolute value will ever be less than that.

Comment: I edited the answer for correctness, thank you for the helpful suggestions. I came up with the basic idea, @Kevin came up with corrective input, I leave it to the OP to select the accepted answer. Anyway, Kev, +1.

Comment: You could also consider breaking the loop if they are exactly the same. You will not find anything closer.

Answer (score 76):

```
var closestTime = listOfTimes.OrderBy(t => Math.Abs((t - fileCreateTime).Ticks))
                             .First();
```

If you don't want the performance overhead of the [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) call then you could use something like the [`MinBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) extension method from [`MoreLINQ`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) instead:

```
var closestTime = listOfTimes.MinBy(t => Math.Abs((t - fileCreateTime).Ticks));
```

Comment: I'm pretty annoyed that this isn't the selected answer.

Comment: Or that it doesn't even show up towards the top. 

Answer (score 8):

```
var closestTime = (from t in listOfTimes
                   orderby (t - fileInfo.CreationTime).Duration()
                   select t).First();
```

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is completely wrong.  What you want is something like this:

```
  DateTime fileDate, closestDate;
  List<DateTime> theDates;

  fileDate = DateTime.Today;       //set to the file date
  theDates = new List<DateTime>(); //load the date list, obviously

  long min = Math.Abs(fileDate.Ticks - theDates[0].Ticks);
  long diff;
  foreach (DateTime date in theDates)
  {
    diff = Math.Abs(fileDate.Ticks - date.Ticks);
    if (diff < min)
    {
      min = diff;
      closestDate = date;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

How often will you be doing this with the same list of times? If you're only doing it once, the fastest way is probably to just scan through the list and keep track of the closest time you've seen yet. When/if you encounter a time that's closer, replace the "closest" with that closer time.

If you're doing it very often, you'd probably want to sort the list, then use a binary search.

Answer (score 2):

get the difference of your file creatime and every time in your list and sort the absolute value of each time difference. the first one should be the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is a generalized solution to the question, "Find the closest time from a list of times".  This solution finds the closest time before and after a given search time.

```
//For finding the closest time in a list using a given search time...

var listOfTimes = new List<DateTime>();
listOfTimes.Add(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2000"));
listOfTimes.Add(DateTime.Parse("1/2/2000"));
listOfTimes.Add(DateTime.Parse("1/3/2000"));
listOfTimes.Add(DateTime.Parse("1/4/2000"));
listOfTimes.Add(DateTime.Parse("1/5/2000"));

var searchTime = DateTime.Parse("1/3/2000");

var closestBefore = listOfTimes.LastOrDefault(t => t < searchTime);
var closestAfter = listOfTimes.FirstOrDefault(t => t > searchTime);

Console.WriteLine(closestBefore);
Console.WriteLine(closestAfter);

/*
searchTime: 1/3/2000
before:     1/2/2000 12:00:00 AM
after:      1/4/2000 12:00:00 AM

searchTime: 1/1/1900 (edge case)
before:     1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM (DateTime.MinValue)
after:      1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM

searchTime: 1/1/2001 (edge case)
before:     1/5/2000 12:00:00 AM 
after:      1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM (DateTime.MinValue)
*/
```

Comment: The question is lacking obviously what the asker did. So kudos to You for caring to even give what You did when you couldn't se an attempt to solve it by the asker, but does your question actually relate to the problem?
You give how to handle a list of time, but what the asker is fishing for is code to get files and read their properties and sort them. ) didn't read it as a question about sorting a list

Answer (score 1):

Use the minimum absolute time difference between the file time and the time in the list. You might get 2 entries being the same, and then you would need a different method to differ between these.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but a question regarding the various LINQ solutions proposed above.  How efficient is LINQ?  I have not written any "real" programs with LINQ yet, so I'm not sure on the performance.

In this example, the "listOfTimes" collection implies that we have already iterated over some file system based objects to gather the times.  Would it have been more efficient to do the analysis during the iteration instead of later in LINQ?  I recognize that these solutions may be more "elegant" or nicely abstract the "collection as database" idea, but I tend to choose efficiency (must be readable though) over elagance in my programming.  Just wondering if the cost of LINQ might outweigh the elegance here?

Comment: In general, LINQ's performance is pretty good. Usually not as fast as the equivalent plain loop, but often close enough that you don't really need to worry about it.

Comment: The problem with all the LINQy answers here (including my own) is that they need to perform an `OrderBy` on the collection which will be much slower than a single O(N) dash using a loop.

Comment: It's up to the OP to decide whether that performance penalty is an acceptable trade-off, *in their particular situation*, for LINQ's improved readability etc.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  There are certainly cases where I can see LINQ really paying off, but I'm always leary of the "wow" factor of new technologies vs good fundamental design decisions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var creationTimes = new [] {DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)};
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("C:/test.xml");
var closestTime = creationTimes
    .OrderBy(c => Math.Abs(c.Subtract(fi.CreationTime).Days))
    .First();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var min = listoftimes.Select(
    x => new { diff = Math.Abs((x - timeoffile).Ticks), time = x}).
    OrderBy(x => x.diff).
    First().time;
```

Note: Assumes at least 1 entry in `listoftimes`.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would update this post to include a real world scenario. I wanted this sort of function as I have a blog showing news of the latest movie screenings.

However I don't want to list screening in the past (ie screening date past the current date) and as I wanted to show a record I needed some sort of ID passed to pick up the record.

I have left if simple so that you can follow the process and no doubt make it more efficient with LINQ et al.

First the model

```
        public class LatestScreeeningsModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

Then the code block you can call from your controller

```
        private static LatestScreeeningsModel GetLatestScreening(IPublishedContent currentNode)
    {
        LatestScreeeningsModel latestScreening = new LatestScreeeningsModel();

        DateTime fileDate;

        // get a list of screenings that have not shown yet
        var screenings = currentNode.AncestorsOrSelf("siteLanguage")
                                   .FirstOrDefault().Descendants("screening")
                                   .Select(x => new LatestScreeeningsModel() { Id = x.Id, Date = x.GetPropertyValue<DateTime>("date") })
                                   .Where(x => x.Date > DateTime.Now).ToList();

        fileDate = DateTime.Today;

        long min = Math.Abs(fileDate.Ticks - screenings[0].Date.Ticks);
        long diff;
        foreach (var comingDate in screenings)
        {
            diff = Math.Abs(fileDate.Ticks - comingDate.Date.Ticks);
            if (diff <= min)
            {
                min = diff;
                latestScreening = comingDate;
            }
        }

        return latestScreening;

    }
```

I am using Umbraco to get the date items but it would work with any custom model, List et al.

Hope it helps