# Java to C# - Display nearest time

Tags: java, c#

A while back I wrote this code in Java whose basic function is to display nearest time when comparing current time with a 'list' that contains times. So far it works and bellow is what I have:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.TreeSet;

TreeSet<LocalTime> times = new TreeSet<>();

        times.add(LocalTime.parse("05:40"));
        times.add(LocalTime.parse("06:40"));
        times.add(LocalTime.parse("08:30"));
        times.add(LocalTime.parse("09:45"));
        times.add(LocalTime.parse("10:35"));
        times.add(LocalTime.parse("11:10"));
        times.add(LocalTime.parse("11:55"));
        times.add(LocalTime.parse("12:20"));
        times.add(LocalTime.parse("13:30"));
        times.add(LocalTime.parse("14:55"));
        times.add(LocalTime.parse("16:00"));
        times.add(LocalTime.parse("16:30"));
        times.add(LocalTime.parse("17:30"));
        times.add(LocalTime.parse("19:00"));
        times.add(LocalTime.parse("20:10"));
        times.add(LocalTime.parse("21:10"));

LocalTime ceiling = times.ceiling(LocalTime.now());
LocalTime first = times.first();

if (ceiling != null) {
            System.out.println("Bus is at: " + ceiling);
        } else {
            System.out.println("There are no more busses at this time. Next one will go in: " + first);
        }
```

So, it takes current time, compare it to the 'times' and display nearest one in it on the screen.

So far the C# version I have is:

```
var timeOfDay = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");

        Console.WriteLine(timeOfDay);

        var time = new SortedSet<DateTime>
        {
            DateTime.Parse("05:40"),
            DateTime.Parse("06:40"),
            DateTime.Parse("08:30"),
            DateTime.Parse("09:45"),
            DateTime.Parse("10:35"),
            DateTime.Parse("11:10"),
            DateTime.Parse("11:55"),
            DateTime.Parse("12:20"),
            DateTime.Parse("13:30"),
            DateTime.Parse("14:55"),
            DateTime.Parse("16:00"),
            DateTime.Parse("16:30"),
            DateTime.Parse("17:30"),
            DateTime.Parse("19:00"),
            DateTime.Parse("20:10"),
            DateTime.Parse("21:10")
        };

        var first = time.First();
        var last = time.Last();

        Console.WriteLine("Bus is at: " + first);

        Console.WriteLine("There are no more busses at this time. Next one will go in: " + last);
```

One last piece of the puzzle will be to display nearest time, in comparison to the current one.

My question is: What is the best way to do such a thing in C#?

Comment: Have you tried this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1757189/1758369

Comment: Please put more care into writing the title of your Question. If your question is about the equivalent of the TreeSet collection, say so.

Answer (score 0):

Must be SortedSet is the same as TreeSet in Java.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.100).aspx

Nearest time

```
   var set = new SortedSet<DateTime>();
    var time = DateTime.Now;

    //2 sample values to test with
    set.Add(time.AddHours(1));
    set.Add(time.AddHours(-1));

    //We temporarily add our time to the set
    set.Add(time);
    var next = set.SkipWhile(a => !a.Equals(time)).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
    var previous = set.Reverse().SkipWhile(a => !a.Equals(time)).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();

    //and remove it in the end 
    set.Remove(time);
```

As Basil mentioned below, for LocalTime you may use [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) library

Comment: How do you know it's the same? Link-only answers are not generally accepted

Comment: SortedSet is indeed the closest in .NET to TreeSet.  The harder part will be determining the equivalent to LocalTime.

Comment: For `LocalTime` on .Net, look at the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) library. Inspired by the Java frameworks, Joda-Time and java.time.