# Group list items based on the minimum time difference

Tags: c#, linq

There are two not equal sized lists of timestamps along with an idx. For example,

```
L1 = {(1,t1), (2,t2),..., (M,tM)} and
L2 = {(1,T1), (2,T2),..., (N,TN)} with M < N
```

For both lists we have `t1<t2<...<tM` and `T1<T2<...<TN`. The timestamps of each list represent the arrival of items though time from two different sources. The goal is to group the touples `(m,tm)` and `(n,tn)` that have `dist(tm,tn)->min` with `dist` as the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757136/find-the-closest-time-from-a-list-of-times)? This means, that the shortest list will be upsampled. A usefull obervationn is, as soon as the `dist(tm,tn)->min` is fullfiled, it is sufficient to stop traversing the longest list. Given that I am totaly new to the linq logic could you please suggest an efficient way to do such a grouping?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you define  "those that are closer in time using timestamps" precisely.

Comment: @VitaliyKalinin for example, given `(k,tk)` a list item in `L2`, it should be grouped with `(m,tm)` where `dist(tk,tm)` is the smallest compared to the rest time stamps in `L1` like in the answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757136/find-the-closest-time-from-a-list-of-times). Also the timestamps in each list are sorted in ascending order.  Thanks for the interest.

Comment: What if only one item in `L2` is the closest for all items in `L1`?

Comment: @GertArnold this is not possible because the timestamps are in ascending order and unique. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: Well, if all items in `L1` are later than the latest item in `L2`, it is. I'm trying to stake out the intended behavior, because you're not too explicit about it. For example, do you want to "exhaust" all values in `L2`? Also, it would help to see some response to the answers give so far.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks again for the interest. I have done an edit to my post. I hope now that it is clear to continue the conversation more safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
L1 = {(1,t1), (2,t2),..., (M,tM)} and
L2 = {(1,t1), (2,t2),..., (N,tN)} with M < N


var result = L1.Select(i => new {idx1 = i.Item1, 
                                 idx2 = L2.Min(l => label(i,l).Item1}
                      );
```

where `label` is a comparison function that assign values to diff between timestamps (the shortest the diff the smaller the value).

Answer (score 1):

I consider this essentially merging the two lists together, assuming they are sorted. In order to do this efficiently you have two options, depending if M and N are of similar size, or if M <<< N (The size of M is much smaller than N)
In both cases, you want to start by sorting the elements in L2 via their timestamps, ascending

**M and N are of similar size**
 In this case, we perform a merge, similar to merge sort.

1. Sort the elements l in L1 in ascending order
2. For each element in L1, travese the elements in L2 until you find the first element with a timestamp larger than l. Now compare this element with the element before it to find which is closer to the timestamp of l, and keep this pairing in a result set.

**M <<< N**
In this case, it may be faster to perform binary search in order to find the closest elements in L2. That is, for each element in L1, do a binary search to find where it would be added to L1. Check the two adjacent elements in L1 to find which has the closest timestamp, and save this pair in a result set.